# Display current import file (html table form) from database into cakephp

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, cakephp

Cakephp version 2.5.1, import file (csv format), database (mssql)

i have imported the csv file and saved into database, after save i want to display each of the 'current' import data using html table in cakephp. My problem is i don't have idea to code for find current batch upload where each batch start point from L01-0-00-00-000
until end L01-0-00-00-999.The L01 on each string will change to L02, L03 and so on.

i try to use this function in mycontroller, it will only show all the table with Line=01

My controller:
`function index () {
$this->set('uploads', $this->Upload->getColumnTypes('all', array('conditions' => array('RAS_Off_Upload.RAS_Code' => ' L01-0-00-00-000' && ' L01-0-00-00-999' ))));
}`

Thank you for any of the suggestion.

Output table in database:
RAS_Off_Upload table

```
No  RAS_Code         Value  Remark  SF  Create_by  CLN       Lot       Prod  Time Date

1   L01-0-00-00-000   0     test    H   D123     CLN12345   SLTC123M  LN2CPW 7:10 25JUN
2   L01-1-01-01-111  68     test    L   D123                                 7:15 25JUN
3   L01-0-01-01-222  40     test    L   D123                                 7:18 25JUN         
4   L01-0-01-01-333  82     test    L   D123                                 7:20 25JUN
5   L01-0-00-00-444  59     test    L   D123                                 7:21 25JUN
6   L01-0-00-00-555  59     test    L   D123                                 7:23 25JUN
7   L01-0-00-00-666  59     test    L   D123                                 7:34 25JUN
8   L01-0-00-00-777  59     test    L   D123                                 7:37 25JUN
9   L01-0-00-00-888  59     test    L   D123                                 7:40 25JUN
10  L01-0-00-00-999   0     test    E   D123                                 7:41 25JUN
```

Comment: What is the format to save in the database? Are you serializing all the records and saving in 1 column or multiple rows at multiple column?

Comment: The format is csv file. I have 9 location running this process.Each process run and save in 1 batch file. Each batch of file have serial number from L01-0-00-00-000 until end L01-0-00-00-999. For e.g the first location will have batch of serial number from L01-0-00-00-000 until end L01-0-00-00-999, then second location have batch of serial number from L02-0-00-00-000 until end L02-0-00-00-999, and so on.So i decide to find each entered  batch by identify the start of string L01-0-00-00-000 and end L01-0-00-00-999.

Comment: Are the records saved in `Line` column? It would be better, if you can post the result what you are getting in output.

Comment: ok, sure i will edit my question again. Thanks!

Comment: The table edited shows the batch file for first location.

Answer (score 0):

I am considering RasOffUpload is your model correspond to `RAS_Off_Upload` table.

Try the following:

```
function index () { 
    $this->set('uploads', $this->RasOffUpload->find('all', 
                array('conditions' => array('RasOffUpload.RAS_Code REGEXP' => '^L01-0-00-00-[0-9]*$')))); 
}
```

Use `find` method instead of `getColumnTypes`. You can also try to use `^L01-0-00-00-[[:digit:]][[:digit:]][[:digit:]]$`.

If in the middle digit is also varies from 0 to 9, then you can use like:
`^L01-[[:digit:]]-00-00-[[:digit:]][[:digit:]][[:digit:]]$`.

Comment: thank you for the comment! I've try this out but nothing display out in my framework.Is it i need to add something on my view ctp file?

Comment: sorry for the late reply, i have tried both methods but it won't work, it will show Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'REGEXP'.